# Is it possible to determine iOS target programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to be able to switch certain functionality on/off in an iOS app depending on whether it is the release version or not. Is it possible to programmatically whether the current build is the release version or not? I know similar functionality can be achieved through the use of macros, but as I understand it these would not work if the code in question is inside a static library.

Comment: `#ifdef DEBUG` should do the trick.

Comment: The DEBUG macro is defined at Target > Build settings > Preprocessor Macros. There will be two entries: Debug and Release. The default is to have a macro DEBUG=1 defined in the Debug entry.

Answer (score 2):

create a flag in your scheme and use it like

```
#ifdef BETA
```

so say you want to have a string method returning two different strings for two different states

```
- (NSString *)someString {

  #ifdef BETA
    return @"Beta String";
  #else
    return @"Release String";
  #endif

}
```

You could use the built in

```
#ifdef DEBUG
```

this would differentiate between release and debug

I wouldnt recommend having two different targets.

Comment: Will this approach still work if I want to supply a static library to another third party? I want to be able to encapsulate the code that turns off functionality if the build is a release build, without the user of the library having to configure this or having any knowledge of it at all.

Comment: it should do if you use the prerequisite DEBUG flag otherwise you would have to make it a stipulation of the framework

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 said:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"Debug mode");
#endif
```

Comment: why would you copy a comment and make it an answer of your own? also, isn't this code missing a closing bracket?

Comment: Because the "comment" was not an answer and it was incomplete?

Answer (score -1):

Just set Target name in your Scheme -> Environment Variables -> add Name and Value. eg: targetName = "mytesttarget"

**Obj-c**

```
NSDictionary* envir = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];  
NSString* targetName = envir[@"targetName"];
```

**Swift**

```
let envir = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment  
let targetName = envir["targetName"]

Now you can check the target condition

if targetName == "mytesttarget" {  
...  
} else {  
...  
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
let envir = ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName  
let targetName = envir["targetName"]
```

Comment: `envir["targetName"]` this returns nil

Comment: To get the Target name: ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName

Comment: Updated for swift 4